# PHP OOP -> if statements in __construct vs calling functions direcly (performane and future)

Tags: php, class, oop, architecture

I have a user class which has username, email and user level and it has methods such as ChangePassword, ChangeEmail, ChangeUserLevel, DeleteUser and Adduser.

Currently the class performs whatever it needs to do based on the data posted to the page which has `$user = new User(name,email,secure_level)`. So for example if you've submited the change password form to the page with instantiated user object in __construct it has several if statments -> such as:

```
If ($_POST['changePassword']) {
    $this -> changePassword(); }
```

and continues like that for other methods of the class. So my question is:

Is this a good way of handling these events or would it be better to do something like:

```
$user = new User(name,email,secure_level);
if ($_POST['changePassword']) {
   $user->changePassword(); }
```

By better I mean performance wise and possible future pitfalls.

(I have Login class, Registration class and Web Page class that are orginised in the similar manner)

Thank you in advance - I've just started learning PHP so I am not sure about anything I do.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the reason I am doing it this way is because all my classes produce error and system messages that are displayed to a user and the classes display them themselves; it just simplifies feedback to the user for me, but I am open minded and will rewrite message handling if this was not a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second option is better. `User` is a Model class (business logic abstraction) and as such shouldn't interact with web requests (`$_POST` and friends) directly, this is a task for a Controller, not for models.

Imagine at some later point you'll have to write a command line script that manages users. If you keep `User` interface clean of web logic, you can reuse it in this script and just change the controller (replace `$_POST[xxx]` with `$argv` or similar).

Comment: That is a very interesting point I will have to consider for the future development (as what i am currently doing is just a leraning experiment just for php sake). Can you explain what do you mean by controller? And to come back to my original question what would be the performance difference between the two approaches? P.S> Sorry, but I can't upvote yet ;/

Comment: Controller is the `C` part in the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) triad, basically, it's a component that gets data from the outside (user input, web requests etc) and relays it further to Models (=business logic) and Views (=output). As for performance, just forget about it as long as you 're learning how stuff works, proper structure and readability are far more important.

Comment: Just a quick follow up question if you don't mind, is it ok to store userUpdate methods in the user class or would it be a better idea to create a separate class that will take a user object and do all the manipulations with it? and why?

Comment: @uFlock: there's no definitive "best" answer to design questions, it always depends. Both patterns ([Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) vs [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html)) have their uses, it's your responsibility as designer to choose what fits better for your use case.

Comment: Although that's a good answer it left me even more confused as I don't see how Data Gateway is more useful for small projects such as simple CMS can you please provide one example of a project where the benefits of implementing Data Gateway will outweigh the development complexity associated with it?

Comment: @uFlock: [The book](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html)  has lots of examples, it's not particularly entertaining IMO, but quite useful read.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to go about it. I personally use one function  in my user class that goes:

```
updateUser($username = null, $password = null, $email = null)
```

And then any field that isn't null will be updated.

Comment: That's a very neat way of handling updating user info, it's a shame I can't upvote yet ;/ But  I don't get how the function knows which parameter out of these i passed to it? or am I going to to need do something like updateUser(null, $password, null); in order to change the password?

Comment: Yes, you have to specify null. The defaults only work after the last argument you supple. So if you're just updating username, you can go updateUser($username); and the rest will be assumed null.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason I can't accept 2 answers and @georg answer was more complete I will upvote you as soon as I get more reputation. Thank you